# Relative efficiency of a test R

Tags: r

I have this problem: Using relative efficiency, compare sign test and t-test. 
this is my code for a power test of 0.85

```
min.num.test.t<-function(n)
{
  x<-rnorm(n,0,2)
  y<-rnorm(n,0,2)
  h<-t.test(x,y,paired=TRUE,alternative="greater")$statistic
 1-pt(h,n-1)-0.85

}

min.num.segni<-function(n)
{
  x<-rnorm(n,0,2)
  h<-binom.test(x=sum(x>0), n=length(x), 
           p = 0.5, alternative ="greater")$statistic
  1-sum(dbinom(h:n,n,0.5))-0.85
}
ntest<-ceiling(uniroot(min.num.test.t,c(10,150))$root)
nsegni<-ceiling(uniroot(min.num.segni,c(17,50))$root)

ifelse((ntest/nsegni)>1,print("test segni relativamente più efficiente per una potenza del test fissata a 0.85"),print("test t relativamente più efficiente per una potenza del test fissata a 0.85"))
```

So, statistically speaking, the problem is to find the minimun sample size which allows to get to the test's power required. then i have to verify if the ratio of the two calculated sample size is greater o less than 1 and so get to a conclusion. 
 I implemented two functions and with uniroot i m trying to solve the two equations in order to find the sample size. the problem is that  when i call uniroot function: it returns me always the max of the interval that i specified, that's sounds strange to me... anyone want to help me? thanks

Comment: If you have trouble understanding meaning of output that statistical procedure gave you, or you don't know if you are using correct statistical procedure, you are probably better off asking at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). If you know that output you are getting is wrong (i.e. there is bug in code), please edit your question in a way that allows people not intimately familiar with your statistical procedures to still help you.

Comment: thnks for the tip. i try to edit to be more clear